# Oracle 10g - Alias column from query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My column is a result of a subquery, I would like to assign a column alias field is extracted from another query, but I can not.

Carry the example does not work:

```
SELECT field1, 
       field2,
       (SELECT FROM mytable WHERE COND1 aa) as [SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE cond2]
  FROM table1
```

is it possible?
thanks

Comment: Not possible until you use dynamic sql

Comment: As suggested by @Madhivanan, you could use dynamic SQL but I would question why you want to do this and perhaps you could implement the functionality you require in a different way.

Comment: And depending on whether `cond2` is comparing something between `myTable` and `table1` (something row-based), this isn't possible with dynamic SQL either.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (excluding ons mentioned by X-Zero) you can do that with multiple queries and dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE 
  v_alias VARCHAR2(30);
  v_query_alias VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  SELECT name 
  INTO v_alias 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE cond2;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT field1
                           ,field2
                           ,(SELECT FROM mytable WHERE COND1 aa) as '||v_alias||'
                     FROM table1';
END;
/
```